# difference between df.loc[:, reversed(colnames)] and df.loc[:, list(reversed(colnames))]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anaconda

`df.loc[:, reversed(colnames)]` can retrieve a slice from df, but can not be used to assign to df. In order to assign to that slice of df, I have to use `df.loc[:, list(reversed(colnames))]`

Observe the following code and output for clarification:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'a':list('asdf'), 'b':range(4)}
        )

print('df==', df, sep='\n')

colnames = ['a', 'b']

print('\ndf.loc[:, reversed(colnames)]:', df.loc[:, reversed(colnames)], sep='\n')

df.loc[:, reversed(colnames)] = np.nan
print('\ndf after df.loc[:, reversed(colnames)]=np.nan:', df, sep='\n')

df.loc[:, list(reversed(colnames))] = np.nan
print('\ndf after df.loc[:, list(reversed(colnames))]=np.nan:', df, sep='\n')
```

and the output:

```
df==
   a  b
0  a  0
1  s  1
2  d  2
3  f  3

df.loc[:, reversed(colnames)]:
   b  a
0  0  a
1  1  s
2  2  d
3  3  f

df after df.loc[:, reversed(colnames)]=np.nan:
   a  b
0  a  0
1  s  1
2  d  2
3  f  3

df after df.loc[:, list(reversed(colnames))]=np.nan:
    a   b
0 NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN
```

This behavior is new. I didn't have to `list()` to do assignment when I was using Anaconda 2018.12, I recently upgraded to Anaconda 2019.03.

I wonder what changed and caused this.

Comment: reversed is now an object in python3.6. I don't remember the version this changed so I won't add that bit, but you now must explicitly call `list()` on a reverse object to change it to a list. The same thing is now applied to `map()` in case you run into something similar in the future.

Comment: @d_kennetz that is a 2->3 change.